# VPC created even after getting error in terraform file

Tags: terraform, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create a `VPC` using Terraform modules but I get the following error

```
Error: error creating EC2 Subnet: InvalidParameterValue: Value (us-east-1) for parameter availabilityZone is invalid. Subnets can currently only be created in the following availability zones: us-east-1a, us-east-1b, us-east-1c, us-east-1d, us-east-1e, us-east-1f.
│       status code: 400, request id: 05392eaa-894a-45fa-8fb2-a414f3d08523
│
│   with module.vpc.aws_subnet.private[0],
│   on .terraform\modules\vpc\main.tf line 378, in resource "aws_subnet" "private":
│  378: resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
```

which is fine but when I check my AWS account I see my VPC is already created, is it an intended behavior by terraform?

Comment: Yes. TF does not roll back. Whatever it created before failure, it stays.

Comment: Your error is on subnet creation, not on VPC.
Can you share us your TF code and check if subnets were created please?

Comment: Thank you Marcin, is there any purpose why TF is designed such a way ( different from Cloudformation )